# Firestore, atomic writes/updates on more than 500 documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, atomic

One of the main reason for using firestore batche writes is that they are atomic and ensure data consistency. However they have a limit of 500 operations. Considering a large application, one may have denormalized user data in more than 500 documents. So when a user updates any of his/her profile details, I have to update it in all those more than 500 documents while maintaining data consistency (atomic updates) at the same time.

An intuitive solution would be maintaining an array of batches, and keeping track of those which fail, and then retry the failed batches manually.

However I want to ask that:

1) If there are any best practices or some other more easy and reliable methods of achieving this, because considering the limit 500 operations per batch, most of the commercial apps have to face the same issue.

2) Also is there a more smart approach present out there than just denormalizing data, so that through "that smart approach", this whole issue of data consistency (as stated above) can be avoided in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> An intuitive solution would be maintaining an array of batches, and keeping track of those which fail, and then retry the failed batches manually.

That's a viable solution that you can go ahead with.

> 1) If there are any best practices or some other more easy and reliable methods of achieving this, because considering the limit 500 operations per batch, most of the commercial apps have to face the same issue.

I can tell you what I do. I usually create a counter variable and increment its value every time I add an update operation to the batch. Then create an if statement and every time you increment the counter, check to see if it reached 500. At that time, commit the current batch, reset the counter and start a new batch, picking up where you left off. Do this till you finish all batch writes.

> 2) Also is there a more smart approach present out there than just denormalizing data, so that through "that smart approach", this whole issue of data consistency (as stated above) can be avoided in the first place.

The problem of the batch writes cannot be solved with the help of denormalization. Duplicating data, isn't a solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method of doing that, but you did not mention that how actually you ensure data consistency or atomic writes across all batches? Do you your use case requires data consistency at all? I mean, considering the example of a user updating his profile, what happens when user's internet connection drops while I have committed say only one batch out of several batches.

Comment: I'm using a single batch at a time. Once the first batch reaches 500 operations, I commit the batch. So I ensure data consistency in the same way you do. If a batch write fails, I'm going to retry writing it. And for the last part of  your comment, you should retry till all batches succeed.